# Concatenation of certified PDFs

Tags: pdf, itext, aspose.pdf

We have a need to concatenate a number of PDFs uploaded by a user into a single PDF file. We're currently using iTextSharp for this without problem for standard PDFs. But sometimes one of the files is certified (e.g. a bank statement issued by the bank) and this is causing a problem. It's treating the operation as an edit, which is not allowed because of the certificate.

My question is: is this going to be possible to achieve, or is there a fundamental reason that it can't be done? What tools could I use and how (iTextSharp, Aspose.Pdf, etc)?

For clarity, I don't want the certificate to be maintained in the concatinated PDF. I would like a standard PDF to be the result. Also, I'm not talking about PDFs protected with a password.

Most of the discussion I can find online is either talking about password protected files, or trying to maintain the certificate.

Many thanks,
Robin

Comment: A certified pdf is a pdf with a certification signature. Thus, all you have to do is to remove that signature. Signatures can have visualisations. If you want to keep that visualisation, remove the signature by flattening the signature field. Otherwise simply remove it from the form fields and page annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certifying a PDF document is to secure it against modification. You may [remove the signature](https://docs.aspose.com/display/pdfnet/Working+with+Signature+in+a+PDF+File#WorkingwithSignatureinaPDFFile-RemoveDigitalSignaturefromthePDFFile) using Aspose.Pdf from certified PDF and later [concatenate](https://docs.aspose.com/display/pdfnet/Concatenate+PDF+Files) the resultant PDF with other PDF documents.

I'm Tilal, developer evangelist at Aspose.